# Ambiguous between Microsoft Sample and WPF Rules

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I thought we should have no reference from View to ViewModel in MVVM Pattern. but just saw an MVVM Sample from code.msdn.microsoft in which ViewModel implements new Window and shows it;

By using MVVM-Light toolkit you use Messenger to Call or Open new Window and Still keep Separate the View and ViewModel form each other. Is it right to reference the View in ViewModel? Or it is wrong;

Do you suggest to call Views Directly from ViewModel for large(or medium) projects?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Easy-MVVM-Examples-fb8c409f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Level of effort and complexity.

MVVM is just a pattern. A pattern you don't have to follow. Any little tool I write for my own use just uses a model, a viewmodel, and a view. The viewmodel exposes all properties I need for the view by INotifyPropertyChanged. The data is moved back and forth from viewmodel to model manually using `ViewModel.FromModel(model)` syntax. I don't bind to my models. I only use the model when saving/loading data; I don't hang onto it. My views are generated using dataTemplates and dataTemplateSelectors. If I have a property that should change the layout I expose that on the viewmodel and use a selector. Otherwise, I have a datatemplate for every viewmodel object. And it just works.

I call this a form of MVVM, even though it doesn't any toolkit or the exact MVVM pattern that Microsoft describes.

I would personally implement a service to drive commands from the viewmodel to generate new views and hookup the viewmodel. But that's because I have MVC experience, and I think generating views is easier to do using the MVC pattern, whereas desktop views work better using the MVVM pattern.

All my views are composed with contentControls. Setting the content is setting the viewmodel.

So I use a hybrid.

If your software isn't so complex to need the complete Microsoft endorsed MVVM pattern, why create the overhead code IMO. YAGNI.

Comment: you mean; if project isn't too big; you don't need to follow MVVM Exactly; yeah? you mean I even I can Implement Button_Click in Code-Behind(at least for those windows which don't have Database transaction);  Don't they make any problem for unit testing?

Comment: Do you need to unit test on a one window three control dialog only application? It's better to refactor in features that you need at the point where you need to grow your application. Would it make sense to develop a full-fledged MVVM enterprise application for a single screen that alters one table in a database. Are you going to use a cloud hosted config file for one setting?

Comment: I'm researching for an SRM; I don't need cloud storage or any other program related; Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

IMO, having a strong reference from the ViewModel to the View has 2 problems:

- It breaks the testability of your ViewModel code. This means you won't be able to Unit Test your code so easily, and if you do you'll have to account for `Dispatcher` issues and the like.
- It makes your ViewModels dependent on WPF assemblies and types. This means you won't be able to literally copy and paste your ViewModels into other applications or platforms such as Xamarin.Android or the like

If none of these are important to you, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't. Not doing so creates additional overhead in your code, by having to implement `WindowManager`s and whatnot.

Comment: you mean having reference from ViewMode to View; ... or Have Reference from View to ViewModel(against MVVM)?

Comment: having a reference from `View` -> `ViewModel` is NOT against MVVM. That's conceptually the same that a `Binding` does. I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry; I made mistake; Thanks for your help;